# write set to file and format

Tags: python, set

I have a set that looks like this:

```
names = {('nevio', 'chetan'),
 ('oishee', 'tafel'),
 ('utas', 'brea'),
 ('zoiie', 'fennell'),
 ('mervi', 'ensing')}
```

I want to write this to file as :

```
'nevio', 'chetan',
'oishee', 'tafel',
'utas', 'brea',
'zoiie', 'fennell',
'mervi', 'ensing'
```

What is the best method to do this?

I have tried this:

```
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    for row in names_list:
        row = str(row)[1:-1] 
        f.write(row)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kindly use this snippet You have to access the index of the values in the Tuple, the snippet given below produces your desired output

```py
names = {('nevio', 'chetan'),
 ('oishee', 'tafel'),
 ('utas', 'brea'),
 ('zoiie', 'fennell'),
 ('mervi', 'ensing')}

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    for name in names:
        file.write(f'{name[0]}, {name[-1]}\n')
```

The f'' String works with the latest version of Python, so if you are using an older version kindly upgrade.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```py
names = {
    ('nevio', 'chetan'),
    ('oishee', 'tafel'),
    ('utas', 'brea'),
    ('zoiie', 'fennell'),
    ('mervi', 'ensing')
}
```

**Convert set to list**

```py
names_list = list(names)
```

**Then use this example.**

```py
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    for i, name in enumerate(names_list):
        f.write(f"'{name[0]}', '{name[1]}'{',' if i+1 < len(names_list) else ''}\n")
```

**Output:**

```py
'nevio', 'chetan',
'utas', 'brea',
'mervi', 'ensing',
'zoiie', 'fennell',
'oishee', 'tafel'
```

---

**What happens here** `{',' if i+1 < len(names_list) else ''}`
If the index of the operated element + 1 is less than the length of the list with the names, then paste the character `','` otherwise the empty string `''`.